# Where should be put a feedback box on a website?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, layout

Is there a special place where to be this kind of section? I have a task to integrate a "feedback box" and I have no idea...

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about User Experience and most likely better fits on UX.SE. In addition, not sure how this can be answered without seeing the layout of a page.

Comment: Hi Rms, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. As @Scott mentions, your question might have a better life at UX.SE, another site in the Stack Exchange network, specialising in User Interaction questions. There's a good chance a moderator will migrate your question there. Don't be discouraged, we are aware that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you! Enjoy the site!

Comment: What a warm welcome. Thank you. I appreciate your answers. Yes, i'm new with this site and this entire network. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Rms,

Feedback call to action can be either a popup like on quorumfcu.org or a sliding button on a side, like on oss-usa.com - depends whether you're integrating existing 3rd party technology that has specific requirements or designing for custom code implementation.  I would start by asking client what plugin they'd like to use for feedback and work off that.